# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow' Command skipped related to Databrics notebook (Azure databrics labs)

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

> This issue is mainly related to "Databrics notebook" provided for Azure machine learning lab notebooks

Answer (score 1):

Add a new cell before the classroom set up and run the following command: This command solve your problem. Above mentioned problem is associated with tensorflow only.

```
`pip install tensorflow`
```